# Can Google glass show information outside the restricted area (top right square)

Tags: google-glass

I have a project to assist hearing impaired people of my country. The google glass may fit perfectly for the usage we plan.

The "restricted area" is actually a limitation for me, as developer, and for them as user, because UX. The "restricted area" makes the developing of some applications impossible.

Is there workaround (hardware or software) for use the full area of google glass lens (I mean the whole visual range)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

When you use Glass, you see images by looking through the display. The display takes up a portion of your field of view, and is designed to be positioned just above your field of view. It cannot display images outside of its edges in the same way that a TV cannot display images beyond its boundaries.